# Pythonic way to write long if statement in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm beginner in python and hope you help me find way to write `if` statement correctly. This is code i have:

```
target_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]
nav_files = [
    x
    for x in target_dir.rglob('conf.yaml')
    if '.'.join(str(x.parent).replace(str(target_dir), '').lstrip('/').split('/')[:2]) in settings.MODULES
]
```

You may see unacceptably long `if` statement. As i understand there are 2 ways to resolve this:

1. Separate `nav_files` preparation and use some `for` blocks
2. Separate `if` statement by linebreaks(if it's possible)

What is the best practice? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what the if statement is supposed to do? This appears to be a file path operation (taking a relative path to ``target_dir``, removing trailing directory, and taking the last two path elements?) which can likely be expressed shorter.

Comment: Note that the general approach to "How can I make <thing> more readable inside <terse expression>" is "Do not cram <thing> into <terse expression>". In specific, a for loop *statement* and utility function for the condition is likely a lot more readable.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Project has modular structure(base_dir/module/submodule/other_files) and there is MODULES list, where items like "core.page". In this ```if``` statement i need filter ```conf.yaml``` files only from enabled modules(existed in MODULES list). As result i need prepare **module.submodule** string from path to compare with MODULES list

Comment: So basically you need the last two path elements, separated by a dot? As in ``/a/b/c/d/e`` becomes ``d.e``? Are there any paths shorted than two elements (after pruning the base), as in ``/a`` becoming just ``a``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, as i see no, modules has 2 parts "module/submodule", there is no just "static", there are "static.page", "static.widget" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a backslash before each newline to combine several physical lines as one logical line. A more common practice in Python is to wrap lines inside parentheses; then Python knows the statement has ho continue, and you don't need a backslash.

```py
nav_files = [
    x for x in target_dir.rglob('conf.yaml')
    if '.'.join(
        str(x.parent).replace(
            str(target_dir), '').lstrip(
            '/').split('/')[:2]) in settings.MODULES
]
```